# Why does systemd wait for a disk not present in `fstab`?

Tags: boot, systemd, fstab, uuid, ecryptfs

My system takes exactly 95 seconds to boot: 5 seconds actual boot and 90 seconds waiting for a nonexistent drive:

```
(...boot.log...)
A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-6bbb4ed8\x2d53ea\x2d4603\x2db4f7\x2d1205c7d24e19.device (1min 29s / 1min 30s)
Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-6bbb4ed8\x2d53ea\x2d4603\x2db4f7\x2d1205c7d24e19.device.
```

This device is not listed in `fstab`, and I did not even manage to find the piece of hardware (usb disks etc.). Where can it come from and how can I disable it?

I have ecryptfs on my home directory, and I have manually disabled swap in order to save my SSD disk.

Comment: Have you made changes to your hardware i.e. copied the system do another disk drive? I had similar problems with a reference in the initrd. Does `grep -r 6bbb4ed8 /etc` find anything? Maybe the problem goes away if you rebuild the initrd. Perhaps `systemd-analyze critical-chain` gives you information where to find the reference.

Comment: @HaukeLaging, the grep solved it! I can't believe I didn't find it earlier. I thought I had tried everything. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file `/etc/crypttab` is a (less known) counterpart of `fstab` for managing crypto filesystems. The default installation of Ubuntu configured an encrypted swapfile:

```
cryptswap1 UUID=6bbb4ed8-53ea-4603-b4f7-1205c7d24e19 /dev/urandom swap,offset=1024,cipher=aes-xts-plain64
```

Originally I had disabled this swap partition in `fstab` only, which is *not* enough.

*Anybody who knows more about the purpose and inner workings of `/etc/crypttab` is welcome to extend this vague self-answer of mine.*

Comment: Did you read the `systemd-cryptsetup(8)` man page?

Answer (score 4):

Use `grep -r 6bbb4ed8 /etc` to find any references to that device and rebuild the initrd afterwards (`mkinitrd`).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Dell Latitude laptop with both boot SSD and data HDD; this latter developed bad sectors, so I eventually backed up data and physically removed the HDD, experiencing at the next boot the 90" timeout for the missing HDD.

`grep -r /etc` as per Hauke's suggestion turned up the entry in `/etc/crypttab` corresponding to the HDD UUID (per `/dev/disk/by-uuid`) which systemd was looking for.

I then remembered adding that line years ago to allow entering a single LUKS password for both disks, pointing the HDD decryption to a keyfile on the root filesystem (which was getting decrypted upon boot with my entering of its LUKS password - see `crypttab(5)` if you're interested in a multi-disk single-LUKS password setup).

Commenting that `/etc/crypttab` line out brought back the quick SSD boot speed (thanks!).